# Antipatterns of IoC container usage. Why IoC containers are so complex and used so "fancy" way?

Tags: ioc-container

I'm seriously start thinking that usage of IoC container provokes to create overdesigned solutions (at least it provokes me to try to use various unnecessary features:).

It's the time to synchronize my "IoC" antipatterns list with community one's..

My short experience tell that it is absolutely enough to call Resolve method once per application at startup to resolve some infrastructure singletons and initiate with them "transient object's factory" that could produce new "smaller life time grain factories" . Even to make those factories thread safe (e.g. create one instance per thread) is so easy to achieve by adding 10 code lines into factory... Still those factories are much more simpler then "library's integration with IoC tool". Interception? Just create your own wrappers... Life time managers / dependency strategies/ parent containers? Call the Resolve only once at bootstrapper and you won't  think about that.

Could you help me to understand why developers call Resolve several times on different application layers (by passing container or by passing delegate to container) and then have a lot of things to think about? I really worry that I miss something.

Comment: Good points. Can you de-verbositize this?

Answer (score 5):

Some kind of IoC are anti-patterns or may be in some cases. For example the [service locator antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). But if you are using constructor injection at the beginning of your application - and only there - then it *should* not lead to an anti-pattern.

Injecting a DI container interface in a class is a wrong use of constructor injection. If DI is not part of the business logic of your class it should not know or depend on DI container nor should it depend on IKitchen. It's only fine to inject your DI container in some kind of helper or service working in conjunction with your dependency injection container, because it's purpose is to work with or around DI container. The examples in the links you give are misuse of IoC. It does not mean that IoC in general is an anti-pattern.

I think the correct question would be "Can constructor injection be an anti-pattern?". So far I've never faced any situation or seen any example where it was so I would say "no", until I face such a situation.

Answer (score 3):

When it was not clear to me how to use an IoC container, I decided to stop using it, because I thought was just an overcomplication over the simple dependency injection.

It is true though that even without IoC is possible to fall in the over-injection cases.
A while ago I read some posts from the author of ninject that opened my mind.

As you already know the injector should be used only inside the context root. However, in order to avoid over-injections, I decided to introduce an exception of the rule for injected factories.

In my framework, factories (and only factories) can use the injector container. Factories are binded in the container in the context root and therefore can be injected. Factories become valid dependencies and are used to create new objects inside other objects, using the injector container to facilitate dependencies injection.

Comment: Yes! I totally agree with you here. Allowing factories to use the container is OK, because what's the alternative? Manually "newing" up objects again? I think people get too hung up on the theory behind these concepts rather than using them as _productivity tools_.

Answer (score 1):

Read [This](http://tavaresstudios.com/Blog/post/Do-classes-need-to-be-DI-friendly.aspx)

Clearly something wrong. New library should not bring additional complex code.

Comment: It would have been nice if you added (quoted) of the article since the link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

I've found somebody who possibly could understand me :)

Constructor [over-injection anti-pattern](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-anti-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

Other antipattern in my eyes is pushing the initialization of container "deeper" then actual bootsrapper.

For example [Unity and WCF recommendations](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.neovolve.com%2Fpost%2F2010%2F05%2F17%2FUnity-dependency-injections-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-2.aspx)

Bootstrapper in wcf app is the service constructor, then just put container initialization to constructor. I do not understand reasons to recommend to go for programming wcf sevice behaiviors and custome sevice host factory: if you want to have "IoC container free"  bootstrapper - it is absurd, if you need to have "IoC container free" service contract implementation - just create second "IoC container free" service contract implementation.