# Writing a library that is dependency-injection "enabled"

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, class-library

I'm working on a project at the moment and it's going to be primarily library-based.

I want the library to be consumed using dependency injection, but I want the library to be largely agnostic towards the container being used.

I wrote a "bridge" library a while back to make this sort of thing easier, but I wasn't sure if this was actually the right approach? (library: https://github.com/clintkpearson/IoCBridge)

I don't want to reference the DI-technology (Ninject, Windsor etc) directly from my library as then it makes it inflexible for people using it.

There are a few other questions on SO in a similar vein but none of them seem to actually address the problem satisfactorily.

**As a side note**: I realise I could just make sure the library adheres to the general idiom and uses interfaces & ctor arguments for dependencies, and then just leave it up to the consuming app to register the types in the containers.

The only issue I can see with this (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that this requires the consuming app to actually **know** which types link to which interfaces, whether some need to be registered as singletons etc... and from a plug-and-play usage perspective that's pretty poor.

Comment: Do you need to allow the user to inject their own implementations(plugins)?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları not necessarily no. They'll most likely want to implement their own versions of some of the interfaces and then they can just chuck them around in place of any other reference. The library itself probably won't centre directly around that sort of implementation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *good* DI implementation should enable DI on any object, **regardless** of the latter being *DI-agnostic* or not.

*Prism* is a **bad example**, as the *last time* I used it (2 years ago) it required objects to be DI-agnostic by enforcing use of the `[Injection]` attribute. A good non-DI-agnostic example is [**Spring Framework**](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) (extremely popular DI framework for Java, has a .NET port called [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/)), which allows enabling DI via so-called **context files** - these are xml files that describe dependencies. The latter need not be part of your library, leaving it as a completely independent dll file.

The example of Spring can tell you that you should not have any specific configuration, prerequisites or patterns to follow in order to make an object injectable, or allow objects to be injected to it, besides the **programming to interfaces** paradigm, and *allowing programmatic access* to suitable *constructors* and *property setters*.

This does not mean that any DI framework **should support** manipulation of plain CLR (.NET) objects, a.k.a. POCO-s. Some frameworks rely only on their specific mechanisms and may not be suitable to use with DI-independent code. Usually, they would require direct dependency on the DI framework to the library, which I think you want to (and probably should) avoid.

Comment: I actually decided to follow this sort of approach in the end. I realised having a bootstrapper in the library driving registration was a bad approach. Instead I'm simply going down the factory / service interface route with default implementations. Calling code can then use any framework they wish to inject the dependencies or do it manually. I'll likely put together some framework-specific wrappers to make this easier and they'll do some auto-wiring on behalf of the calling code.

Comment: I am glad being helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit [controversial](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2009/07/14/just-say-no-to-poor-man-s-dependency-injection/) but I suggest using Poor Man's Injection. I'm not saying it's great but it has some valid use cases(just like Service Locator) under some constraints. It will require a little more maintenance but it will save you from depending another libray for IoC container registration. You should read [Mark Seemann's article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) on the subject.

I recently implemented this approach in a very [simple library](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/SimpleMvcSitemap) of mine. Basically you write two constructors for the public classes of the library.

```
internal SitemapProvider(IActionResultFactory actionResultFactory, IBaseUrlProvider baseUrlProvider)
{
    _actionResultFactory = actionResultFactory;
    _baseUrlProvider = baseUrlProvider;
}

public SitemapProvider() : this(new ActionResultFactory(), new BaseUrlProvider()) { }
```

As you can see only the second constructor is public and you fill the dependencies yourself. This also provides encapsulation at assembly level. You can still test this class by adding a [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to the assembly and use dependency injection in your library freely. The user can also create instances with new keyword or add this class's interface to their IoC registration.

I don't know if there's a widely adopted IoC container registration library in .NET. I thought about writing one myself but each container has their unique features and it gets more complicated with object life cycles. Also people will be uneasy about depending on another library for this.

Comment: Thanks! Some really interesting points there. Some of my other projects have used variations on these "types" of IoC. I think the best approach is probably going to be to make the library as blind to the fact it'll be within a container at all. Except for a simple e.g. `ITypeResolver` interface or something. Then maybe have per-container libraries that provide a resolver to the library and do all the container magic there. I think for general-purpose use and flexibility something like my IoCBridge is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have slightly misinterpeted the scope of Dependency Injection. DI is a pattern, a subset of IoC, and IoC containers make DI easy and convenient - they assist with dependency *resolution*. IoC can be categorised as a superset of several methodologies, [of which DI is one part](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

**You do not need IoC frameworks in order to make Dependency Injection work.**

If you really insist on using an IoC container instead of leveraging regular DI (i.e. constructor parameters or mandatory property setting) then you should nominate the container/framework, don't try to be all things to all people by trying to kludge together adapters or bridges. Be cautious about over-engineering. A library by its very definition means it has a limited and well defined set of functionality, therefore it should not need a large amount of dependencies injected.

> They'll most likely want to implement their own versions of some of the interfaces

You don't need an IoC framework to achieve this. If your constructors have their parameters defined as interfaces then in effect you've already achieved DI - the dependency is injected at construction time and you know nothing about the actual concrete implementation of it. Let the calling code worry about the nitty gritty details of which implementation of that interface it wants to pass in.

Comment: -1 Because that's clearly not the case for all libraries, some of them are quite large despite being narrow in scope.

I also mentioned that I was aware of being able to simply follow the pattern at-large and the user could then opt to wire it all themselves, but that's not exactly great.

Using a single IoC container type for the library is also not great because then some users won't be able to integrate it into their own apps particularly well. Libraries like Prism / Caliburn.Micro support differing IoC containers, so it's clearly a done thing.

Comment: @Clint I'm sorry I don't get your point. Library "size" and "scope" are not necessarily proportional, and for you to take one little sentence and nit pick that means you've missed what I was saying - possibly because what I said doesn't fit with the preconception you had. If I haven't been clear about something then by all means ask me to explain. If you are determined to over-engineer I can't stop you, but I can advise you against it.

Comment: @Clint Your comment about Prism makes me think you have totally misunderstood what I was saying. [Read about Prism here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). I think it is quite clear in that article that the **calling code** does the resolution, so your library doesn't need to know about any container. In fact [passing an IoC container](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.nz/2010/11/first-commandment-thou-shalt-not.html) to a caller can be an [anti pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7564121/109702).

Comment: Prism has a bootstrapper type that it relies on for requesting instances from an external source, so therefore it's geared toward supporting containers. This is the crux of my question. What is the best approach to achieving this within a library?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Great set of comments, you should wrap them up as an answer.

Comment: @Clint, checkout [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805066/writing-a-library-that-is-dependency-injection-enabled/21839192#21839192).  I hope reconsider downvoting this answer, as it does not say anything wrong. If you insist on using Prism, you'd better check if you can make it work for normal objects, or reformulate your question to include that you need it to work with Prism specificly. DI frameworks differ, and some are not as liberal and compatible to non-DI-code as Spring is.

Comment: @slugster, thanks. I removed the comments and added an answer. I wonder why I did not do that in the first place, but thankfully, SO is wiki-like